# Не всегда вызывается handle accept в Debug. (Boost Asio, Ubuntu, Clion)

Tags: c++, linux, сеть, clion, asio

Функция HandleAccept(...) не всегда вызывается в режиме отладки. Поэтому прихоится перезупускать сервер и конектится, если присоединился, то далее все работает. Иногда приходится повторять раз 10 и более. Приложение закрыл и все по новой. Если просто запускать, то шансов больше.

```
static boost::asio::io_service *g_stcpIOService = nullptr;
static boost::thread *g_stcNetServiceThread[64] = {0};

void NetServiceRun()
{
    g_stcpIOService->run();
}

void CKernel::InitNetService(INT32 n32ThreadCount)
{
    for(INT32 i = 0; i < n32ThreadCount; ++i) {
        g_stcNetServiceThread[i] = new boost::thread(&NetServiceRun);
    }
}

void CKernel::PrepareForNextAccept()
{
    m_shpNewConnecion.reset(new CConnection(*g_stcpIOService));
    m_pAcceptor->async_accept(m_shpNewConnecion->GetSocket(),
                              boost::bind(&CKernel::HandleAccept, this,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void CKernel::HandleAccept(const boost::system::error_code & ec)
{
    if(!m_pAcceptor->is_open()) {
        LogPrintDebug("Acceptor Close");
        return;
    }
    if(!ec) {
        LogPrintDebug("Handle Accept Succes");
        m_ConnectionManager.Start(m_shpNewConnecion);
    } else {
        LogPrintDebug("Handle Accept Error: %s", ec.message());
    }
    PrepareForNextAccept();

}

bool CKernel::Initialize()
{
    InitNetService(1);
    m_pAcceptor = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(*g_stcpIOService);
    m_pSocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*g_stcpIOService);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*g_stcpIOService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve({"127.0.0.1", "1973"});

    m_pAcceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
    m_pAcceptor->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    m_pAcceptor->bind(endpoint);
    m_pAcceptor->listen();
    PrepareForNextAccept();
}
```

Функция acync_write не выдает ошибки. при отправке если сервер не вызывает HandleAccept

```
async_write(m_Socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer,size),[this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
        if(!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "async_write ok " << std::endl;

            DoReadHeader();
        }
    });
```

Если вызвать netstat при этом.

```
cucaracha@cucaracha-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ netstat | grep 1973
tcp        0      0 localhost:58642         localhost:1973          ESTABLISHED
tcp       20      0 localhost:1973          localhost:58642         ESTABLISHED
cucaracha@cucaracha-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:63342         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:1973          *:*                     LISTEN     
...
```

Полный код [github](https://github.com/tarakan012/MiningSimulatorGameServer/blob/master/src/Kernel.cpp)

Comment: Использование  'C с классами' и статических переменных в комбинации с boost::asio и выглядит довольно жутко. Чем вам стандартные примеры boost::asio  не угодили? Что касается вопроса, я не вижу явных ошибок, но есть подозрение, что `HandleAccept` всё же вызывается, но с ошибкой. Или же программа повисает где-то в другом месте, вешая пул потоков, на котором крутится `io_service`. В любом случае отладчик вряд ли создают проблему, скорее он меняет быстродействие функций, из-за чего проблема проявляется чаще, чем без него.

Comment: @Ariox Ecли вы про конструкцию #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { , то в ближайшее время вычищу код, IDE NetBeans автоматом добавляла. А чем плохи в данном случае статические переменные? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет, я про ручное управление временем жизни ресурсов - использование сырых указателей вместо хранения по значению или в умных указателях, и про игнорирование стандартных контейнеров stl. Те же потоки можно хранить в `boost::thread_group` или в `vector`, а не в массиве указателей. Со статическими переменными может быть много проблем, что самое печальное - неожиданных. И удобству отладки они не способствуют. В вашем случае они просто не нужны - если нужен какой-то общий объект - достаточно хранить ссылку или `shared_ptr` на него, хотя у меня вообще есть сомнения, что общий объект нужен.

Comment: @Ariox Спасибо. Учту.

Comment: @Ariox А можно узнать какой общий обьект вы имели ввиду, который возможно не нужен.

Comment: Насколько я понял, у вас статическая переменная используется только для вызова `CKernel::HandleMsgFromGC` из одного из методов `Connection`. Вместо этого `m_GCMsgHandlerMap` можно обычным членом  `CKernel`, а в  `Connection` можно хранить ссылку на `m_GCMsgHandlerMap`, передавая её в конструкторе. Единственная проблема - в этом случае все объекты `Connection`  нужно удалить до создавшего их экземпляра `CKernel`. Или можно хранить  `m_GCMsgHandlerMap`  в `shared_ptr` - тогда порядок удаления владельцев не важен.

Comment: Я не нашел, где инициализируется `m_GCMsgHandlerMap`, но можно сделать её локальной статической переменной функции, избежав основных проблем статических переменных, [примерно так](https://godbolt.org/g/6yNB9R). `std::string_view` (или boost::string_ref/string_view`) позволяет вернуть статическую строку из динамической библиотеки, если вам это нужно. В этом случае статическая переменная оправдана, но делать статической переменной весь класс `CKernel` я бы не стал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в следующем: у вас задача запускается так:

1. Создание `io_service`
2. Создание потоков
3. Запуск задачи на ожидание подключения клиентов

Но у `io_service` есть одна особенность: цикл событий крутится только до тех пор, пока в нём есть задачи. Т.е. если после создания потоков они сразу запустятся, до того, как главный поток добавит в очередь задание на ожидание подключения, потоки просто завершатся, т.к. в очереди еще нет задач.

Способа решения два - либо создавать потоки после того, как будет вызвано ожидание подключения, либо до создания потоков создавать объект `io_service::work`, который не позволит завершиться потокам до того, как экземпляр `io_service::work` будет уничтожен.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.